# Mathematica's equivalent to the Python's Zip command in List-comprehension?

Tags: functional-style, python

What is Mathematica's equivalent to Python's ZIP command? Is this called nesting? It means iterating over sub-sets of values like the below example. How can I do it in Mathematica?

**Example in Python that I want in Mathematica, I want the ZIP!**

```
>>> [(ii,jj) for (ii,jj) in zip((1,10,100),(2,20,200))]
[(1, 2), (10, 20), (100, 200)]
>>> [(ii,jj,kk) for (ii,jj,kk) in zip((1,10,100),(2,20,200),(3,30,300))]
[(1, 2, 3), (10, 20, 30), (100, 200, 300)]
```

**[Update] question got solved, Python's Zip is Transpose in Mathematica. The real challenge is now how to operate it like Spherical-Cartesian conversion below**

```
**Mathematica Example: input as spherical (L,Azimuth,Phi) and output as cartesian (x,y,z), how?**

    L = {874, 4513, 1487};
    A = {120 Degree, 140 Degree, 180 Degree};
    Inc = {14.1 Degree, 66.2 Degree, 66.2 Degree};
    tuple = Transpose[{L, A, Inc}];
    hhh = Print[N[{#1*Cos[#2], #1*Sin[#2]*Cos[#3], #1*Sin[#2]*Sin[#3]}]] &[r, \[Theta], \[Phi]];
    hhh @@ tuple
```

Comment: Check `Map` and `Transpose`. Or maybe `Thread` does what you want? `In[135]:= Thread[f[{1, 10, 100}, {2, 20, 200}, {3, 30, 300}]]

Out[135]= {f[1, 2, 3], f[10, 20, 30], f[100, 200, 300]}`

Comment: I asked this in [SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25984273/equivalent-to-pythons-zip-in-list-comprehension-for-mathematica), hopefully attracting some Python/Mathematica guru to see this. There must be some elegant solution to do this.

Comment: Why did you `Thread[Times[...]]` instead of threading `List`?

Comment: As noted above, `Thread` is the equivalent to `zip`. `MapThread` provides control similar to list comprehension.

Comment: It is so much easier to write things in [Pastie](http://pastie.org/9586178), I wrote a bit larger example that I want.

Comment: `MapThread[Function[{x,y,x},x+y+z],{xlist,ylist,zlist}]` is pretty darn close to `[x+y+z fir x,y,z in zip(xlist,ylist,zlist)]`

Comment: Or even `MapThread[Plus,{xlist,ylist,zlist}]` for that particular case

Comment: Sorry @george2079 and @mfvonh - I didn't see your comments before posting my answer. I do think that `MapThread` is what the OP is looking for.

Comment: @Verbeia I wish I knew even myself: manipulating tuples requires to be just some super guru in Mathematica, syntax so hard in comparison to Python, cannot understand how to get inside that -- trying to do the same example Spherical-Cartesian now with the ready CoordinateTrasform and MapThread (not working), why? http://i.stack.imgur.com/M8dCh.png

Comment: **Update** did the code in two different methods, MapThread just not working yet [here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/ySiIZ.png), why?

Comment: @hhh it isn't working because you do not have the [correct syntax for [`Function`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Function.html), which is `Function[{args},CoordinateTransform[(* etc *)]][args]`. Note the `[args]` at the end. I'd suggest using the pure function form if you are going to put it in a `MapThread`. **You do not need to be a "super guru", you just need to pay attention to the documented syntax.**

Comment: similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/160216/foreach-loop-in-mathematica

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The function you want is [`MapThread`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MapThread.html) - no `Transpose` needed.

```
MapThread[f[#1, #2, #3] &, {L, A, Inc}]

(* {f[874, 120 \[Degree], 0.246091], f[4513, 140 \[Degree], 1.15541], 
 f[1487, 180 \[Degree], 1.15541]} *)
```

And for your function:

```
MapThread[N[{#1*Cos[#2], #1*Sin[#2]*Cos[#3], #1*Sin[#2]*Sin[#3]}] &, 
 {L, A, Inc}]
(* {{-437., 734.102, 184.394}, {-3457.16, 1170.64, 2654.21}, {-1487., 0., 0.}} *)
```

**EDIT**: And for your other function - note the use of [`SlotSequence`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SlotSequence.html):

```
SpherCat = CoordinateTransform["Spherical" -> "Cartesian", {##}] &

(* CoordinateTransform["Spherical" -> "Cartesian", {##1}] & *)

MapThread[SpherCat, {L, A, Inc}]

(* CoordinateTransform::bdpt: Evaluation point {1487,180 \[Degree],1.15541} is 
incompatible with the coordinate assumptions of the specified coordinate chart. >> *)

{{734.102, 184.394, -437}, {1170.64, 
  2654.21, -4513 Cos[40 \[Degree]]}, 
 CoordinateTransform[
  "Spherical" -> "Cartesian", {1487, 180 \[Degree], 1.15541}]} *)
```

There seems to be an error in your input (perhaps you intended the reverse transformation?) but the question of how to simply and elegantly operate on the lists you want is dealt with.

Comment: Can you elaborate this with another function such as the ready CoordinateTransform where you don't specify the & explicitly? How to use MapThread with it? I am trying to do it with it now to replace the self-done function [here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/M8dCh.png). I must say that I am so confused to Mathematica, why on earth they cannot get the shxt out and design the syntax clean (sorry just frustrated in trying to understand a simple thing like tuple manipulation).

Comment: I did it in two different ways. I got one method working but MapThread not working http://i.stack.imgur.com/ySiIZ.png, trying...

Comment: @hhh, as mentioned in my other comment, that's nothing to do with `MapThread` and everything to do with incorrect syntax for the full form of `Function`. Also **kindly stop moving the goal posts by revising the question and function of interest**. No wonder this question has been downvoted.

Comment: I like the fact that you are never giving up +1, real hxcker attitude! Sometimes it is muddy but always fighting to the goal. Thank you.

Answer (score 16):

You could get the lists you want simply by entering them as a nested list and transposing it:

```
In[60]:= Transpose@{{1, 10, 100}, {2, 20, 200}}

Out[60]= {{1, 2}, {10, 20}, {100, 200}}
```

and

```
In[61]:= Transpose@{{1, 10, 100}, {2, 20, 200}, {3, 30, 300}}

Out[61]= {{1, 2, 3}, {10, 20, 30}, {100, 200, 300}}
```

Comment: Actually, you are right in this +1 -- took me a long time and Freenode gurus to hit me a little! Transpose is the equivalent to Python's Zip -- dxmn I got a new question [here](http://pastie.org/9586186). The real challenge is how to operate the tuples in Mathematica by the Spherical-Cartesian function. Somehow with ## and &...ideas?

Comment: `zip[{} ..] := {};
zip [p : xs__] /; MemberQ[{p}, {}] := {};
zip[p : Repeated[_List, {2, \[Infinity]}]] := Join[Through[{Apply[First[{#}]&,
{##}, {1}]&}[p]], zip[(Rest[{##1}] & @@@ {p}) /. {x__List} :> Sequence[x]]]` one can use this implementation as well for sub-lists of same or different lengths

Answer (score 1):

Here's an answer to the question you have now erased.

```
questions = {"name", "quest", "favorite color"}; 
answers = {"lancelot", "the holy grail", "blue"};
"What is your " <> questions[[#]] <> "? It is " <> answers[[#]] <> "." & /@ Range[3]
```

{"What is your name? It is lancelot.", 
"What is your quest? It is the holy grail.", 
"What is your favorite color? It is blue."}

Comment: Err I provided an easier example to make question easier to understand, could you update? I felt this example was not as clear as the latter one. There must be something as succint as in Python built in to Mathematica, always trying to find the most elegant solution.

Answer (score -1):

God in Freenode helped to find some material related to this one, important to become more self-aware of things! Tuple ordering is not trivial thing. Starting the succicnt summary here!

**Summary**

- [Pair lists to create tuples in order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5370848/pair-lists-to-create-tuples-in-order) covering ragged tuple ordering, Python's zip can be implemented with many different methods such as Flatten for ragged case and Transpose for non-ragged case